# mapstruct ambiguous exception when using helper class

Tags: mapstruct

Using mapstruct **v1.0.0.Final**, I'm facing an ambiguous mapping exception trying to map from `SourceType` to `TargetType`:

```
class TargetType {
  List<TargetTypeChild> children;
  boolean allResults;
}

class SourceType {
  List<SourceTypeChild> children;
  boolean allResults;
}
```

The mapping that I'm using is:

```
@Mapper(uses = B.class)
interface A {
    @Mapping(target = "children", source = "children", qualifiedBy = ToTargetType.class)
    TargetType toTargetType (SourceType source);

    @Mapping(target = "children", source = "children", qualifiedBy = ToTargetTypeNoDetails.class)
    TargetType toTargetTypeNoDetails (SourceType source);
}

interface B {
    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface ToTargetType {}

    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface ToTargetTypeNoDetails {}

    @ToTargetType
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedBy = ToTargetType.class)
    List<TargetTypeChild> withDetails(List<SourceTypeChild> value);

    @ToTargetTypeNoDetails
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedBy = ToTargetTypeNoDetails.class)
    List<TargetTypeChild> noDetails(List<SourceTypeChild> value);

    @ToTargetType
    @Mappings({ 
      @Mapping(target = "details", source = "details"), 
      ...rest of mapping 
    })
    TargetTypeChild toTargetTypeChild(SourceTypeChild source);

    @ToTargetTypeNoDetails
    @Mappings({ 
      @Mapping(target = "details", ignore = true), 
      ...rest of mapping 
    })
    TargetTypeChild toTargetTypeChildNoDetails(SourceTypeChild source);
}
```

This does not compile, giving the following exception in both interface A's methods:

> Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property "List children" to List: List noDetails(List arg0), List withDetails(List arg0).

There is one **workaround** to this: put both interface A's methods in interface B. That compiles and works. But I need to separate them for business reasons.

Could anyone explain why the first approach doesn't work and the workaround does?

As a bonus question, if I only code 1 method for mapping (no qualifiers), I don't need to even declare the `@IterableMapping` method, mapstruct knows how to find the "children" methods. 
Why?

Thank you all!

Comment: At which line do you see the compile error? If you say it works with all methods I am inclined to say it's a bug, but I need to dig a bit further.

Comment: Btw. what happens if you omit the explicit list mapping methods from `B`? They should be generated as private methods automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone could explain why the first approach doesn't work and the workaround does?

Your qualifier annotations must at least have retention policy `CLASS`, only then they will be discovered. That's not needed if everything is defined within the same source file, in which case `SOURCE` is enough.

> As a bonus question, if I only code 1 method for mapping (no qualifiers)

MapStruct will generate (private) iterable mapping methods as needed. Actually it should work also in your original case, seems like that's a glitch we need to fix. I've filed issue [#707](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/707) for this.

Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Thanks @Gunnar! Changing the retention policy to CLASS made it work. Only the "bonus" question remains, but I see that it's being taken care of in issue #707.